# Unable to use the dynamic mail configs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I want to override the default mail settings in config/mail.php or .env which Laravel uses by default. I'm setting up the dynamic configs (coming from DB) but email when sent is still going from the "from" address set in the config/mail.php or .env.

Any suggestion for the above words??

Here's the part of the code I'm using:

```
$mailConfigs = [
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'port' => $dbSettings->smtp_port,
    'host' => $dbSettings->smtp_host,
    'encryption' => $dbSettings->smtp_encryption,
    'username' => $dbSettings->smtp_email,
    'password' => $dbSettings->smtp_password,
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'from' => [
        'address' => $dbSettings->smtp_email,
        'name' => 'XXXXX'
    ],
];

Config::set('mail', $mailConfigs);

// print_r(Config::get('mail'));
// Config here are reflected correctly if printed but when email is sent, it again uses the "from" address which is setup in .env and totally ignores the one setup above.

$res =  Mail::send([], $data, function ($message) use($mailConfigs)
{
    // email body, etc...
});
```

Comment: If you config `$mailConfigs` manually, It sent mail correctly?

Comment: I tried but it still picks the configs from .env

Comment: run `php artisan config:cache`